# Access 2016 Web App View allow query null

Tags: database-design, ms-access, view

I'm designing an Access 2016 Web App for inventoring our computers.

Here you see the view:

[image: View]

[image: Overview_Query]

Some of those are queries. The problem is with SSD-Storage and HDD-Storage.

The query looks like that:

[image: Query]

and the result:
[image: result]

Problem is that there should be way more PCs, but they aren't shown because for example they have no HDD or SSD so the query is empty. On some I did not put in the motherboard and so on. I set default values for the view-fields.

**How can I get the view to show me something like 0 or null for all fields without values?**

Comment: You need a left join, an immediate if and an isnull function. Post a formatted SQL statement for a proper answer.

Comment: there is no such thing in access web apps (afaik). The query aboth is all I have for that.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, I am also quite new to the Access Web App, so this might not work/you may have already tried it.

Could you add in a ">0 Or Is Null" criteria (or something similar) to the HDD and SDD fields?

It might help if you gave us more details about the specifics of your tables, especially which [TABLE].[FIELD]s are related to which.

Comment: I added the query for the view where you can see the relationships. Wouldn't a criteria just return less values? I want more. Tried loads of IIFs but I'm completly stuck,